# Discord.js v13 trying to collect button and check the button id

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, collect, discord-buttons

I am trying to collect a button and then check if button.id is cash , here is my code

```
      const msg = message.reply({embeds: [dembed], components: [row1, row2]}).then(function (msg) {

        const filter = i => {
          i.deferUpdate();
          return i.user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        
        const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: 'BUTTON', filter ,time: 15000 });

        collector.on('collect', i => {

          if(i.customId === 'cash') {
            msg.channel.send("test")
          }
        })

        })
```

Comment: Please explain the behaviour you are getting. Are you getting any unexpected errors or anything of that sort?

Comment: nothing just not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the [`messageComponentCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector) you are telling it to monitor the first message which the user posted for any button clicks. Since the buttons are in the `msg` variable instead of the `message` variable, you will just need to change that one to `msg`. Your fixed code should look like this:

```js
const msg = message.reply({ embeds: [dembed], components: [row1, row2] }).then(function (msg) {
    const filter = i => {
        i.deferUpdate();
        return i.user.id === message.author.id;
    };
    const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: 'BUTTON', filter, time: 15000 });
    collector.on('collect', i => {
        if (i.customId === 'cash') {
            msg.channel.send("test")
        }
    })

})
```